# How to make iframe work properly in iOS safari

Tags: html, css, iframe, safari, responsive

I'm having trouble with displaying a Bootstrap responsive page inside an `iframe` in iOS safari browser. It works fine in Android Chrome.
In one of the `iframes`, the page loses its responsiveness and doesnt even scroll (horizontally as well as vertically).
In another iframe, a different page loses its footer and vertical scrolling displays the content behind the `iframe`.

[The page which loses responsiveness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xilvI.png)

[Scrolling issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K9L9.png)

Used the following code

```
<iframe src="add.php" frameborder="0" overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:hidden; style="height:100%;width:100%;"></iframe>
```

separately tried the following

```
<iframe src="add.php" frameborder="0" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></iframe> 

iframe{
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

As well as :

```
iframe {
    width: 1px;
    min-width: 100%;
    *width: 100%;
}
```

Using jQuery 1.11.3, Boostrap 3.3.5, respond.js, html5shiv.js, modernizr.js

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: It's due to this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149264

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
iframe {
    border:none;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This will make your `iframe` fit to the screen so that, everything remains on your view.
and make sure that, you have removed `margin` from body

[Here is preview of W3Schools in iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOB0N.png)

Hope works fine.

Comment: not working, killed the existing responsiveness as well